# Python compares two arrays and save to text file

Tags: python

My goal is to compare all lines in "all.txt" with "blacklist.txt". Any matches will be removed and saved to "all_cleaned.txt". However, my current code is EXTREMELY slow. I have to do this for millions of records, and sadly this is not fast enough. Any suggestions to speed it up will be appreciated

```py
import os
input_file = "all.txt"
blacklist_file = "blacklist.txt"

i = 0

with open(input_file, "r") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    new_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip().lower()
        print(str(i) + ": " + line)
        i = i + 1
        if line not in new_lines:
            new_lines.append(line)

output_file = "all_cleaned.txt"
print("Writing data ...")
with open(output_file, "a+") as fp:
    fp.write("\n".join(new_lines).lower())
```

Comment: If both files contains millions of records, and they are not ordered, then this will be slow anyway, but extremely slow in Python. You may want to opt and search for another tool to do this.

Comment: Your current code doesn't even open the blacklist file; that doesn't help.

Comment: What are the requirements for the data format? Does it have to be flat? How do you plan to use it?

Comment: You want to do this with stream oriented tools (like `uniq` and `sort` in *nix).  But if you *have* to do it in python, sorting (if order doesn't matter) will help, as will not keeping everything in ram (if the files are really that enormous).

Comment: Also, everything after `lines = fp.readlines()` can be outside the `with` block, as it is not file IO anymore. However, as pointed out by @9769953, you are not even using `blacklist_file` in the current code. Besides, provide some sample data as to make this into a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
And: `os` is not used, so no need to import it.

Comment: Presumbly, the blacklist file is much shorter. So read that first and add all of its stripped/lowercased lines to a set. Then you can open the input/output files together and write each input line that's `not in blacklist` to the output file. There's no need to create any intermediate lists: just iterate over the input file directly and write each matching line to the output file.

Comment: python has a `set` data structure. you should use it.

Comment: you say "slow". how many seconds exactly? for a file with how many lines, how large in bytes in total?

Comment: Why are using lower() twice? The appended line is already in lower case owing to first lower function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set` data structures.

```py
input_file = "all.txt"
blacklist_file = "blacklist.txt"
output_file = "all_cleaned.txt"

# files are iterable. the elements are the lines of the file.

input_set = set(open(input_file))
blacklist_set = set(open(blacklist_file))

okay_set = input_set - blacklist_set

with open(output_file, "a") as fp: # a is append, using that since the question did
    fp.writelines(okay_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are iterating through millions of records, naturally it will take some time.  I would recommend a multithreading or multiprocessing approach that looks at some chunk of the data for each thread or process and compares against the blacklist.

Answer (score -1):

```
file1 = open("all.tx.txt", "r+")
file2 = open("blacklist.txt", "r+")
f1 = file1.readlines()
f2 = file2.readlines()


def algo():

    duplicate = []
    unique = []
    superunique = []

    for item1 in f1:
        if item1 in f2:
            duplicate.append(item1)
        else:
            unique.append(item1)
        superunique = set(unique) - set(duplicate)
    print("Duplicate values: ", duplicate)
    print("Unique Values: ", unique)
    print("Super Unique Value :", superunique)

algo()
```